# R Language, Regular Expression to Return a One Character Matches in a Four Character String

Tags: r, regex, string, match, character

In the code below I read some file names into R. The actual number of files is much larger, but this is a representative example.

```
folder <- here("test_data2")

files <- basename(list.files(path=folder,full.names=TRUE, pattern= "*tab.cut$"))

files <- 
[1] "A_r1_D7__A-Prokka_1.tab.cut"      "AB_r1_D7__A-Prokka_1.tab.cut"     "AB_r2_D7__A-Prokka_1.tab.cut"    
 [4] "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_1.tab.cut"     "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_10.tab.cut"    "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_11.tab.cut"   
 [7] "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_12.tab.cut"    "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_13.tab.cut"    "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_14.tab.cut"   
[10] "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_15.tab.cut"    "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_16.tab.cut"    "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_17.tab.cut"   
[13] "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_18.tab.cut"    "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_19.tab.cut"    "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_2.tab.cut"    
[16] "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_3.tab.cut"     "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_4.tab.cut"     "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_5.tab.cut"    
[19] "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_6.tab.cut"     "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_7.tab.cut"     "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_8.tab.cut"    
[22] "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_9.tab.cut"     "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_1.tab.cut"  "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_10.tab.cut"
[25] "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_11.tab.cut" "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_12.tab.cut" "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_13.tab.cut"
[28] "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_14.tab.cut" "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_15.tab.cut" "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_16.tab.cut"
[31] "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_17.tab.cut" "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_18.tab.cut" "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_19.tab.cut"
[34] "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_2.tab.cut"  "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_3.tab.cut"  "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_4.tab.cut" 
[37] "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_5.tab.cut"  "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_6.tab.cut"  "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_7.tab.cut" 
[40] "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_8.tab.cut"  "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_9.tab.cut"  "ABCD_r1_D14__C-Prokka_1.tab.cut" 
[43] "ABCD_r1_D14__C-Prokka_2.tab.cut"  "ABCD_r1_D14__D-Prokka_1.tab.cut"  "ABCD_r1_D14__D-Prokka_2.tab.cut" 
[46] "ABCD_r1_D14__D-Prokka_3.tab.cut"  "ABCD_r1_D14__D-Prokka_4.tab.cut"  "ABCD_r1_D14__D-Prokka_5.tab.cut" 
[49] "ABCD_r1_D7__A-Prokka_1.tab.cut"   "ACD_r2_D7__C-Prokka_1.tab.cut"    "ACD_r2_D7__C-Prokka_2.tab.cut"   
[52] "ACD_r2_D7__D-Prokka_1.tab.cut"    "ACD_r2_D7__D-Prokka_2.tab.cut"    "ACD_r2_D7__D-Prokka_3.tab.cut"   
[55] "ACD_r2_D7__D-Prokka_4.tab.cut"    "ACD_r2_D7__D-Prokka_5.tab.cut"    "AD_r1_D7__A-Prokka_1.tab.cut"    
[58] "CD_r2_D7__C-Prokka_1.tab.cut"     "CD_r2_D7__C-Prokka_2.tab.cut"
```

But let's say I want to use the regular expression in the list.files() function to filter out those files that do NOT contain "B" among the first four characters.

I would think what's below is the proper pattern. What I'm trying to say in the beginning with `\\D{1,4}[B]` is to return any character string from 1 to 4 characters that contains "B".

```
B_files <- list.files(path=folder,full.names=TRUE, pattern= "\\D{1,4}[B]_([rR][123])_D\\d{1,2}__B-Prokka_\\d{1,2}.tab.cut$")
```

But this only returns those files that begin with "AB". Those that begin with "ABCD" are not in the output.

However, when I slightly alter the code by adding the `?` quantifier, I suddenly get an output with files that begin with both "ABCD" and "AB" :

```
B_files <- list.files(path=folder,full.names=TRUE, pattern= "\\D{1,4}[B]?_([rR][123])_D\\d{1,2}__B-Prokka_\\d{1,2}.tab.cut$")
```

Can somebody tell me what's going on here? I though `?` was lazy, meaning it will search for the shortest possible string. Thus, shouldn't the addition of the  `?` quantifier return only the files starting with "AB"?

And, overall, is my regular expression the right way to go about filtering those files that contain the character "B" within the first one to four characters?

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can use the pattern specifying the start (`^`) of the string followed by followed characters that doesn't include the 'B' with `^` inside the square bracket

```
"^[^B]{4}.*tab\\.cut$"
```

We can do the inverse with `grep`

```
grep("^[^B]{4}.*tab\\.cut$", files, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_1.tab.cut"     "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_11.tab.cut"
```

#### data

```
files <-  c( "A_r1_D7__A-Prokka_1.tab.cut"  ,  "AB_r2_D7__B-Prokka_1.tab.cut",  "ABCD_r1_D14__B-Prokka_11.tab.cut", "CD_r2_D7__C-Prokka_1.tab.cut"    , "ACD_r2_D7__D-Prokka_4.tab.cut"    )
```

Comment: My apologies. I worded my question incorrectly. I have made an edit, saying that I want to filter out those files that do NOT contain B. Thus, I want anything in the first four characters that DOES contain "B".

Comment: Thank you, akrun. Might you, or anyone else, also have any idea why it seems to work when I use the `?` quantifier?

Comment: @CAM_etal where you are using the `?`

Comment: @CAM_etal i guess it is jusst based on your data.  You can test it with `"^\\D{1,4}_([rR][123])_D\\d{1,2}__B-Prokka_\\d{1,2}.tab.cut$"` also workss

Comment: In my last block of code, in the pattern argument of list.files(), right after [B].

Comment: @CAM_etal yes, i found it.  I would say that the pattern in the comment above is also working correctly on the `files` example i posted.  So, it is just not sspecific

Comment: @CAM_etal with a better example, you can test it `v1 <- c("AAAA_b", "AB____a", "BAAA_ab"); grep("\\D{1,4}", v1, value = TRUE)#
[1] "AAAA_b"  "AB____a" "BAAA_ab"
> grep("\\D{1,4}[B]?", v1, value = TRUE)#
[1] "AAAA_b"  "AB____a" "BAAA_ab"`

Comment: If you check my pattern (without the endiing) `grep("^[^B]{4}", v1, value = TRUE, invert  = TRUE)#
[1] "AB____a" "BAAA_ab"`

Comment: Ah, nice idea. I will give it a try. Thank you 

Answer (score 1):

```
dat <- c("A_r1_D7.cut", "AB_r1_D7.cut", "ABCD_r1_D14.cut",
         "ACD_r2_D7.cut", "CD_r2_D7.cut", "B.c")
```

You can write:

```
grep("^.{0,3}B", dat, value=T)
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/OSTUN83947)

or

```
grep("^(?=.{0,3}B)", dat, value=T, perl=T)
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/FNUDS3999)

Both return

```
[1] "AB_r1_D7.cut"    "ABCD_r1_D14.cut" "B.c"
```

Note that the latter must use the PCRE regex engines as the default engine does not support *positive lookaheads* (or lookarounds generally).

Comment: This is the more slightly concise kind of answer that I'm looking for. But unfortunately the syntax is for Ruby, not R. First time I've seen the demo explanations/website; it's really handy!

Comment: The problem is that `list.files` regex engine cannot be set to PCRE. It only accepts a TRE pattern.